# Change line height of Hugo theme smol

Tags: css, r, hugo, blogdown

I want to modify the line height of this theme, but I can't find a valid solution.

Github: https://github.com/colorchestra/smol

summary.html controls the home page:

```html
<article>
<p class=small>- <time>{{ .Date.Format (default "2006-01-02" .Site.Params.dateFmt) }}</time> - <a href="{{ .Permalink }}">{{ .Title }}</a></p>


{{ range .Params.tags }}
<!--    <a href="{{ "/tags/" | relLangURL }}{{ . | urlize }}">{{ . }}</a> -->

    {{ end }}
    <div>
        {{ .Summary }}
        {{ if .Truncated }}
        <!--    <a href="{{ .Permalink }}">Read more...</a> -->
        {{ end }}
    </div>
</article>
```

css:

```css
html {overflow-y: scroll}
:root { --bgcolor: white; --fontcolor: #444; --linkcolor: #00e; --visitedcolor: #551a8b; --precolor: #fff; --prebgcolor: #000;}
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) { :root { --bgcolor: black; --fontcolor: white; --linkcolor: #5bf; --visitedcolor: #ae5ee0; --precolor: #fff; --prebgcolor: #383838;}}
body{max-width:800px;margin:40px auto;padding:0 10px;font:14px/1.5 monospace;color:var(--fontcolor); background: var(--bgcolor)}a:link{color: var(--linkcolor)}a:visited{color: var(--visitedcolor)}a:active{color: var(--visitedcolor)}h1,h2,h3{line-height:100%}
p > code{color: var(--precolor); background: var(--prebgcolor); padding:2px}
pre{color: var(--precolor); background: var(--prebgcolor); padding:24px; overflow-x: auto}
article{padding:24px 0}
.center {display: block;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;width: 100%;}
figcaption {color: #888; font: 12px/1.5 monospace; text-align: center;}
figure {margin: auto}
img {display: block; max-width: 100%; height: auto; margin: auto}
```

I tried changing the line-height of the second line, but nothing works.

Thanks for help!